# how to create a model where optimization starts from scratch every time we change the learning rate?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

Maybe someone can help me out - I am playing with learning rate in a Sequential model. I want the optimization to start from scratch every time I change the learning rate, to give a fair comparison of how each learning rate did in the results. So how to create a function in python that generates a new model to optimize the learning rate in a loop?

```
""" optimizing learning rate""" 

# Create list of learning rates: lr_to_test
lr_to_test = [0.000001, 0.01, 1]

# Loop over learning rates
for lr in lr_to_test:
    print('\n\nTesting model with learning rate: %f\n'%lr )

    # Build new model to test, unaffected by previous models
    model = Sequential()

    # Add the layers
    model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_cols,)))
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1))

    # Create SGD optimizer with specified learning rate: my_optimizer
    my_optimizer = SGD(lr=lr)

    # Compile the model
    model.compile(optimizer=my_optimizer, loss='mean_squared_error')

    # Fit the model
    model.fit(predictors, target, epochs=10)
```

As the results I get:

```
Testing model with learning rate: 0.000001

Epoch 1/10
534/534 [==============================] - 0s 661us/step - loss: 120.5427
Epoch 2/10
534/534 [==============================] - 0s 29us/step - loss: 111.6158
.....
Epoch 10/10
534/534 [==============================] - 0s 59us/step - loss: 65.8593


Testing model with learning rate: 0.010000

Epoch 1/10
534/534 [==============================] - 0s 693us/step - loss: nan
Epoch 2/10
534/534 [==============================] - 0s 59us/step - loss: nan
Epoch 3/10
534/534 [==============================] - 0s 29us/step - loss: nan 
....<>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over a list of learning rates and evaluate the result at the end so as to understand which rate works best for you.

```
learning_rates = [0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1]
best_lr = 0
best_rmse = 999999
for lr in learning_rates:
    """Build sequential model"""
    my_optimizer = SGD(lr=lr)

    """Compile, fit and evaluate"""
    rmse = "Calculate your evaluation metric"

    if rmse < best_rmse:
        best_rmse = rmse
        best_lr = lr
```